# Python and FileIO

Tags: python, python-3.x, file

I've written a bunch of functions that deal with handling files on a Linux system. I'm looking for critique on the whole class, in particular:

- Exception handling
- Efficiency
- Style

I'd also like to discuss the practice on marking all these methods as static and using a class merely as namespace.

As far as I'm aware, all methods do what they should. Backwards compatibility with Python 2.x is a nonissue.

```
import os


class FileIO:

    @staticmethod
    def find_subdir(filename):

        try:
            for root, dirs, files in os.walk(os.getcwd()):
                if filename in files:
                    return os.path.relpath(root)

        except IOError as e:
            print(filename + " not found: " + str(e))


    @staticmethod
    def find_in_subdir(filename):

        try:
            for root, dirs, files in os.walk(os.getcwd()):
                if filename in files:
                    return os.path.join(root, filename)

        except IOError as e:
            print(filename + " not found: " + str(e))

    @staticmethod
    def find_file(filename, directory):

        try:
            for root, dirs, files in os.walk(directory):
                if filename in files:
                    return os.path.join(root, filename)

        except IOError as e:
            print(filename + " not found: " + str(e))

    @staticmethod
    def copy_file(source, destination):

        try:
            copyfile(source, destination)

        except Exception as e:
            print("Couldn't copy file: " + str(e))

    @staticmethod
    def check_file(path):

        try:
            os.path.exists(path)
            return True

        except Exception as e:
            print("File not found or not accessible: " + str(e))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- **Docstrings**: You should include a `docstring` at the beginning of every method/class/module you write. This will allow documentation to identify what your code is supposed to do. [PEP-8 Docstring Conventions](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#documentation-strings)
- **String formatting**: Concatenating variables and strings can become messy. Instead, use a format string `f""` to directly include variables into your string, without having to type cast them or alter them in any way to allow them to be added with strings.
- **Use specific exceptions (when you can)**: Catching a general `Exception` isn't always the best idea. If you're preforming a task that generates only a specific kind of exception, catch that one.

> I'd also like to discuss the practice on marking all these methods as static and using a class merely as namespace.

In this context, it's perfectly fine. All of these methods have the functionality of being used and called as a static method.

***Updated Code***

```
"""
Module Docstring:
A description of your program goes here
"""

import os

class FileIO:
    """
    Namespace class for handling files on a Linux system
    """
    @staticmethod
    def find_subdir(filename):
        """
        Finds the subdirectory from `file_name`

        :param filename: Name of the file (duh)

        """
        try:
            for root, dirs, files in os.walk(os.getcwd()):
                if filename in files:
                    return os.path.relpath(root)

        except IOError as e:
            print(f"{filename} not found: {e}")

    @staticmethod
    def find_in_subdir(filename):
        """
        Finds a file in a subdirectory

        :param filename: Name of the file (duh)

        """
        try:
            for root, dirs, files in os.walk(os.getcwd()):
                if filename in files:
                    return os.path.join(root, filename)

        except IOError as e:
            print(f"{filename} not found: {e}")

    @staticmethod
    def find_file(filename, directory):
        """
        Find a file in a directory

        :param filename: Name of the file to find
        :param directory: Directory to find the file

        """
        try:
            for root, dirs, files in os.walk(directory):
                if filename in files:
                    return os.path.join(root, filename)

        except IOError as e:
            print(f"{filename} not found: {e}")

    @staticmethod
    def copy_file(source, destination):
        """
        Creates a copy of a file at `source`, and places it at `destination`

        :param source: Path to the file to be copied
        :param destination: Path where the copied file should be placed

        """
        try:
            copyfile(source, destination)

        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Couldn't copy file: {e}")

    @staticmethod
    def check_file(path):
        """
        Checks if the passed file exists

        :param path: Path to the file

        """
        try:
            os.path.exists(path)
            return True

        except FileNotFoundError as e:
            print(f"File not found or not accessible: {e}")
```